How can I write underscript within a line?
How can I write underscript within a line?
When if I use double $$, then this is normal,
$$H_1 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j )$$
But when I write it within a line ,
$H_1 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j )$
how strange, this is same mathjax code, why it doesn't work within a line?
Solution: just add \displaystyle to it, $H_1 = \displaystyle \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j )$

Does this answer your question? MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference In particular, see this answer

You can use \limits, for example:
\bigcup\limits_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n (H_1 \cap H_j) $\bigcup\limits_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n (H_1 \cap H_j)$,
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k$,
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1n $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1n$.

As a general bit of advice, I would suggest that you don't do this.  Using \limits or \displaystyle for inline mathematics messes up the spacing, and ends up creating text which is rather ugly.  Additionally, as a person with dyslexia, I find irregular line spacing to be an impediment to reading---I find it harder to read and understand text with wonky and unexpected formatting. :/

I agree, and I would put it another way: if the inline version of a formula looks ugly and confusing, you should take that as an indication that it ought to be a displayed formula, rather than an inline formula formatted as if it were a displayed formula.
